# How to conver an char array to string on C++?

Tags: arrays, string, char

I need to convert a char array to string to use the string on a finite automaton, i've tried `char[50]=string` but it copies it indeed but has rubbish on in, char array has to be determinated, no more than 6 letters and i can't find another way, at least on C++ to make it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post at least some of your code so we know what you *actually* did rather than what you *think* you did.

Comment: `char[50]=string` isn't valid code. Show us what you've tried, or we can't tell you what's wrong. You can usually just construct a string from a char array if it's 0 terminated.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a C style string (char array) to a [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), you can use the following code:

`std::string foo = c_style_string;`

In addition, the variable on the *left-hand side* of the assignment operator (equal sign) is changed to the value of the variable on the *right-hand side*. `char[50] =  string` will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

- Convert char array to string

  char cArray[12] = "hello world";
  string str(cArray);